# How can I make the active tab of a bootstrap twitter extend down to hide a fieldset border?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML and CSS in this: http://jsfiddle.net/dSJGe/

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
         <fieldset>xxx</fieldset>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="profile">test</div>
    </div>
</div>

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
padding: 1em 1.667em 1.667em 1.667em;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
-webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
-moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
border-radius: 0.25em;
margin-bottom: 1.667em;
position: relative;
z-index: 89;
padding-top: 1.667em;   
}
```

What I would like is for the tab bottom border and the fieldset top border to be combined. Also when the active tab is selected I would like that to show a white border at the bottom of that tab to make it look like the tab is connected to the fieldset area.

I have tried every combination of bottom-margin, z-index and just about everything else but still cannot get this to work. Has anyone else come up with a solution for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the styles for the fieldset why not apply to the tab-pane?
I edit some styles too.
Copy and paste to your example this CSS code:

```
.nav-tabs {margin-bottom:0px;}
.tab-pane {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-top:0;
    padding: 1.667em;
    margin-bottom: 1.667em;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0.25em 0.25em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0.25em 0.25em;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.25em 0.25em;
}
```

This will make the tabs content all equal

Comment: I like this idea very much but when I made a fiddle with this it doesn't look quite right: http://jsfiddle.net/5CxLg/

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom style to `.nav`.

Change:

`<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">` to 
`<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 0;">`.

I have added `margin-bottom:0` because by default in `bootstrap.css` `.nav` has a bottom margin of 20px. Just remove that and it works :).

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/dSJGe/1/)